# samsung s9 Charging time

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-9

My new Galaxy s9 is taking around 1 hr 39 mins to completely charge the battery. I checked with Samsung customer care they said it should take normally 50 mins to 1 hr.

They did some test on mobile to see is there any other app is preventing to charge, but nothing helped to see the problem. So before I send the devices back to them, I just wanted to see did any of us is facing this kind of issue or is it normal to take this long?

Comment: Thanks for reading my post and your valuable questions. I tried the adapter and cable that came with the device only, and also I have tried with another Samsung provided adapter and cable as well. Then after I did a factory reset and tried. I have almost tried everything you said except the airplane mode. I take your words and the whatever is mentioned the in att website. Then my mobile seems to be working as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why Samsung support would tell you that a full charge cycle is less than an hour... All references I have found, like [this](https://www.att.com/devicehowto/tutorial.html#!/stepbystep/id/stepbystep_KM1273298?make=Samsung&model=SamsungG965U&gsi=ERJacto) one, indicate a normal charge time from 0-50% of around 36-40 minutes, and a full charge cycle from 0-100% would be in the range of 1hr 37min to 1hr 45min using the stock A/C wired charging adapter.

There are many possible things that could make this charge cycle time take longer, but not less time. I am not aware of anyway to get it in the time frame you were told.

I believe your device is functioning normally and your charge time of 1hr 39min falls well within the normal range.